# Ideal of upper triangular matrices over non noetherian ring.

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian

Let $T$ be a ring of upper triangular matrices over $R$, where $R$ is a commutative non Noetherian ring. Let $J$ be a right ideal of $T$. Why $J$ can be written as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I_1&I_2\\
0&I_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $I_1,I_2,$ and $I_3$ are ideals of $R$ satisfying $I_1 \subseteq I_2$?

Comment: Your question though engaging seems a little unclear to me.  I'm having trouble understanding the structure of $J$.  It looks like a block upper triangular matrix, but what does it mean for such a matrix to have an ideal as an entry?  Do you mean the blocks are composed of elements from those ideals?  Can you clarify?  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

That is not a correct description.

The collection $\begin{bmatrix}0& x \\ 0&y\end{bmatrix}\in J$ only forms a right $R$ submodule of  $\begin{bmatrix}0& R\\ 0&R\end{bmatrix}$, and it is not always possible to find two right ideals of $R$ such that the submodule is the sum like this.

You should take a look at this [A first course in noncommutative rings by Lam - Proposition 1.17 about triangular rings.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3372534/29335)

It has nothing to do with the ring being non-Noetherian.